# Keep form data with back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

there are many questions similar to this but none of them seem to help with my situation.

I am developing a three step process using Javascript and html

I have 2 forms in the first two steps.each with a next/prev button
I need to be able to go back from step two back to step 1 and still have step ones form data in the fields. I am rather new to javascript any help would be appreciated. I am unsure how to save the form data and then insert it when the user goes back from step 2

EDIT:
I have decided to use JS to hide/show forms, please can someone tell me why my variable never gets to currentStep == 3; this causes issues when going back as it goes back to step one becasue the currentStep value is stuck at 2

```js
var currentStep = 1;

function nextStep() {

if (currentStep ===1){
  
        $("#petmain1").hide();
  $("#petmain2").show();
  $("#addproduct").show();
  $("#firstimage").hide();
  $("#secondimage").show();
  currentStep = 2;
  console.log("Current step is " + currentStep);
        
 }else if(currentStep ===2){
  
  $("#petmain2").hide();
  $("#addproduct").hide();
  $("#secondimage").hide();
  $("#petmain3").show();
  $("#thirdimage").show();
  $("#firstimage").hide();
  currentStep === 3;
  console.log("Current step is " + currentStep);
  
 }

}
function prevStep() {
 

if (currentStep ===2){
        $("#petmain1").show();
  $("#petmain2").hide();
  $("#addproduct").hide();
  $("#firstimage").show();
  $("#secondimage").hide();
  currentStep = 1;
  console.log("Current step is " + currentStep);
 }else if(currentStep === 3){
  $("#petmain3").hide();
  $("#thirdimage").hide();
  $("#secondimage").show();
  $("#petmain2").show();
  $("#addproduct").show();
  currentStep === 2;
  console.log("Current step is " + currentStep);
 }

}
```

Comment: i think u should use wizard having multiple form or use cookies to store data.

Comment: You should have the all the form in the same page that way you can access all the values of the form

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds is right, make the forms sit in the same page but outside the screen for the previous and next steps, when you want to go back just change the margin - left property

Comment: Better to hide the forms using `display: none`.

Comment: Here I have demo for you. This is working perfectly, I found this demo [HERE](https://www.formget.com/multi-step-form-using-jquery-and-css3/) <!-- begin snippet: js hide: true --> <!-- language: lang-js --> $(document).ready(function() { var count = 0; // To Count Blank Fields /*------------ Validation Function-----------------*/ $(".submit_btn").click(function(event) { var radio_check = $('.rad'); // Fetching Radio Button By Class Name var input_field = $('.text_field'); // Fetching All Inputs With Same Class Name text_field & An HTML Tag textarea var text_area = $('textarea'); // Validating

Comment: Ok I have decided on this route but I am having an issue. Should I post the code to my original question?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

On navigating from first step to second step you can store the value

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     localStorage.setItem("someKey", $("#somField").val());
} else {
     //
}
```

Again on navigating from second to first step check the local storage for the value and assign it to the fields in first form

```
$("#somField").val(localStorage.getItem("someKey"))
```

Comment: would cause in error......;) and how would you determine which value has to put in which input?

Comment: @Jai can you please elaborate

Answer (score 6):

You may use `sessionStorage`.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  Username : <input type='text' id='name'> <br />
  Password : <input type='password' id='password'> <br />
  <input type='button' onclick='storedata()' value='submit'>
</form>
<p id='res'></p>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (sessionStorage.name && sessionStorage.password) {
      document.getElementById("name").value = sessionStorage.name;
      document.getElementById("password").value = sessionStorage.password;
    }
};

function storedata() {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    sessionStorage.name = name;
    sessionStorage.password = password;

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Your datas restored";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

Working Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/d83ohf6L/